# How to apply Coupon in IAP?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm implementing a `video purchasing (digital products selling) App`, where user have to buy particular Video for watching. Videos are uploading from web Admin. The scenario is that Apple doesn't allow 3rd party payment gateway for `digital goods`. So I have to integrate IAP in my application. I've followed these links - [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39031572/is-in-app-purchase-applicable-for-ebooks-audiobooks) & [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29861332/using-generic-in-app-purchase-items-for-a-dynamic-range-of-digital-products?rq=1). One interesting part of my app is that I'm serving variety of coupons for discount,

Now I'm little bit confused **how to manage IAP if user apply any coupon and how to charge them with discounted amount**?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19353708/6315441

Comment: @RaziTiwana I will follow this. Thanks :)

Comment: If you need coupons for subscription IAPs, this is now possible with the new iOS Subscription Offers: https://www.revenuecat.com/2019/03/12/subscription-offers